# Solving cubic equation CAS vs cardanos', not the same result!

Tags: cubics

Really hope someone can help me! I've been struggling with this issue the past 5 hours and can't seem to figure out why or simply don't understand the outcome.

I'm solving a cubic equation using the "depressed equation" method and then cardanos' formula. 
If I solve the cubic equation in my CAS (TI-Inspire) I get one result, but if I solve the depressed equation via cardanos' method, I get a different result. Isn't those two results suppose to be the same (finding the root)?

I get a complex number as the result, but I think I'm suppose to get the real number solution. Am I doing something wrong here?

Thanks in advance
Mike

[image over calculations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S12yd.png)

Comment: can you give us the complete formulas you used?

Comment: All cubics have 3 solutions:  1 real and 2 complex (non-real) solutions, or all 3 solutions are real.  I'm guessing the CAS is only showing you one of the 3 possible roots, and your two different inputs are producing 2 different roots (of the 3 possible) to show you as output.  I suggest modifying your input to the CAS to show all three solutions in both cases.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/UktNjJc.png 

I used the Cardanos' formula for depressed equation :)

Comment: A bit unsure, but the Cardanos' formula is only for when p & q in the depressed equation are of positive numbers? If so, how do I handle the negative P value I have? (-3.25)